# create executing a command with a sequence of files as the input, comma separated

Tags: bash, unix, terminal

Forgive me, this may be a simple operation, but I am coming from object oriented programming languages, and this is not very intuitive to do in unix/bash/terminal.

Say I want to execute a command a list of files, `file1,file2,file3` so the command would read

```
cmd -i file1,file2,file3
```

Now, say I have 1000 files like this. I'd like to just run it through all of the files. However. If I merely enter

```
cmd -i file{1..1000}
```

I receive an error. This is because `file{1..1000}` returns a list that looks like

```
file1 file2 file3 file4....
```

And I need it to return
    file1,file2,file3,file4,....

Comment: Rewrite the command to expect the file names as separate arguments, so the obvious works.  Comma-separated lists on command lines are definitely 'not natural' because it is hard to get it right (unnecessarily hard, especially as you just have to dissect the names inside the program).

Comment: I agree. If I wrote the command I would do this. Unfortunately, its an independent package of commands developed for a particular set of bioinformatic analyses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use `printf` here:

```
cmd -i $(printf "%s," file{1..999})file1000
```

Comment: Works great, and is the simplest / most straightforward code offered up!

Answer (score 1):

With bash builtins:

```
printf -v string "file%s," {1..1000}
cmd -i  ${string%,*}
```

Comment: Hmmm; the `-v string` option to [`printf`](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#index-printf) is interesting.

Answer (score 1):

If you really must do it (see my comment: you should rewrite your code to make your life easier), then:

```
cmd -i $(echo file{1..1000} | tr ' ' ',')
```

The `echo` generates the file names with blanks separating them; the `tr` command maps the embedded spaces to commas.

But you really need to rewrite your command so it expects each file name as a separate argument.